# Sidebar with pictures and a scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering if there was a way of making a side bar with js, html or bootstrap that has a single row of images under drop down tabs with its own scroll bar. I hope i'm specific enough and you get a rough idea of what i would like to achieve

I'm not asking for you to write code just to be pointed in the right direction

Comment: @depperm i tried making a side bar with bootstrap then adding images into in under dropdown tabs so far no luck iv'e tried google and i got nothing hence why im here

Comment: show us the code of what you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap makes this all possible, all of the info you need to build the tabs is available [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs). Obviously you need to call in the Bootstrap JS and CSS file into your HTML page.

To make a `.tab-pane` area scrollable add `overflow:auto;`. Add `white-space: nowrap;` to make your images inside that tab run horizontally.

Demo on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/matthewelsom/pen/pJaZXK).

Hope that points you in the right direction.

```css
aside {
  width: 300px;
}
#one {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<aside>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a href="#one" aria-controls="one" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#two" aria-controls="two" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Two</a></li>

</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="one">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x50">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x50">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x50">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50">
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="two">
  I am another Tab!</div>
</div>
</aside>
```